# Two different versions of python3 installed in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I use Ubuntu and I am new to it .
I have installed python3 in my machine but,

when in terminal I write the command:`python3 --version`

then , it show:`Python 3.6.9`

and when i write the command: `python3.7 --version`

then it shows:`Python 3.7.7`

Does it mean that there are 2 versions of python installed in my machine? If so, then how can i remove Python 3.6.9 and keep Python 3.7.7?

Comment: Yes. you have two version of python installed.

Comment: To remove python 3.6.9 try: `sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.6.9`. Although, the advice is not to uninstall `python 3.6.9` in ubuntu as it is baked into it.

Comment: You indeed have two python3 versions installed - but it's not an issue at all (I have half a dozen Python 2.x and 3.x versions installed), and since `python3` points to the 3.6.9 version you may want to think twice before removing it, it might be needed by the system.

Comment: You should use virtual environments!